# Does the Common Language Infrastructure (CLI) have different versions an can that cause incompatability?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to sort all these .NET terms.
This is what I think:
There is the CLI (Common Language Infrastructure) standard.
There are different implementations (different .NET Framework versions, .NET (and Core), and other for different OSs) that implement the CLI and use the same CIL (Common Intermediate Language). They differ in the APIs they offer. Some APIs are offered by all of them and thus some CIL-Files will run on all versions of all implementations.

From the view of the abstract .NET platform offered, is the only difference between implementations the API?
If I compiled a C# file in .NET 8.0, may it still run in .NET-Framework 4.0?